# Show that $V(I \cap J)=V(I) \cup V(J)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals

Let $I$, $J$ ideals of $K[x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n]$.

I want to show that $$V(I \cap J)=V(I) \cup V(J)$$

I tried the following:

$$\subseteq: $$

Let $x \in V(I \cap J)$.

From the definition of $V$:

$V(S)=\{ (a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n) \in K^n| f_a(a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n)=0 \forall a \in A\}$

we have that $f(x)=0, \forall f \in I \cap J$.

So, $f(x)=0, \forall f \in I \text{ AND } f \in J$.

So, $f(x)=0, \forall f \in I \text{ AND } f(x)=0, \forall f \in J$.

So, $x \in V(I) \text{ AND } x \in V(J)$.

So, $x \in V(I) \cap V(J)$.

But... I have to show that $x \in V(I) \cup V(J)$.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: The mistake is in the second line that begins with "So". The AND cannot be split like that.

Comment: @Arthur How could I write it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $x$ is neither in $V(I)$ nor $V(J)$ (i.e. $x \notin V(I)\cup V(J)$). That means that there is an $f\in I$ and a $g\in J$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ and $g(x) \neq 0$.

We have $fg \in I\cap J$, but $fg(x) \neq 0$, and therefore $x \notin V(I\cap J)$.

This shows that $x \notin V(I)\cup V(J)$ implies $x \notin V(I\cap J)$, which is the contrapositive of what you want to show.

As for the direct approach, how about something along these lines?
$$
x \in V(I\cap J) \implies\\
\forall f\in I\cap J: f(x) = 0 \implies\\
\forall f \in I, g\in J: fg (x) = 0\implies\\
\forall f \in I, g\in J: f(x) = 0 \text{ OR } g(x) = 0 \implies\\
x \in V(I) \text{ OR } x\in V(J)\implies\\
x \in V(I)\cup V(J)
$$

Comment: Why do we conclude from $$\forall f \in I \cap J: f(x)=0 $$ that $$\forall f \in I, g \in J: fg(x)=0$$ ?

Comment: Because if $f \in I$ and $g \in J$, then $fg \in I\cap J$.

Comment: How do we conclude that if $f \in I$ and $g \in J$, that $f \cdot g \in I \cap J$ ? :/

Comment: By the definition of an ideal, since $f \in I$, we must have $fg \in I$. In exactly the same way, since $g \in J$, we must have $fg \in J$. But then we have $fg \in I$ and $fg \in J$, which gives $fg \in I\cap J$.

Comment: Arthur Could you explain me why after saying that $\forall f \in I \cap J:f(x)=0$, we take a $f \in I$ and a $g \in J$, such that $fg(x)=0$?

Comment: We want to show that either $x$ is in the zero set of $I$, or it's in the zero set of $J$. So we take a random function $f$ from $I$ and a random function $g$ function from $J$. By my last comment, we know that $fg \in I\cap J$, which means that $fg(x) = 0$. But then we must have either $f(x) = 0$ or $g(x) = 0$, and we're done. Note that the $f$ in one line has a slightly different meaning than the $f$ in the other line. I could've written $\forall g \in I, h \in J: gh(x)=0$ instead, without changing the meaning of anything.

Comment: Arthur Could we prove $\supseteq$ like that?
$$\text{Let } x \in V(I) \cup V(J)$$
$$\Rightarrow x \in V(I) \text{ OR } x \in V(J)$$
$$\Rightarrow \forall f \in I: f(x)=0 \text{ OR } \forall g \in J: g(x)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \forall f,g \in I \cap J: f(x)g(x)=0$$

$$\Rightarrow \forall \phi(x) \in I \cap J: \phi(x)=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x \in V(I \cap J)$$

Comment: So, $V(I \cap J) \supseteq V(I) \cup V(J)$

Comment: Therefore, $V(I \cap J)=V(I) \cup V(J)$.

Comment: That way is easier. Let $x\in V(I)\cup V(J)$. Then it's either the case that $\forall f\in I: f(x) =0$ or it is the case that $\forall g\in J: g(x)=0$. Now, if a function $h$ is in $I\cap J$, then no matter which of the above applies to our $x$, we have $h(x) =0$, since $h$ is in both ideals.

Comment: What do you mean with " no matter which of the above applies to our x"?

Comment: @evinda I mean that for any single $x\in V(I)\cup V(J)$, it's either the case that $x\in V(I)$, and therefore $\forall f\in I: f(x) =0$, _or_ it's the case that $x\in V(J)$, which means that $\forall g\in J:g(x)=0$ (might also be both, mind you). No matter which one it is, though, whenever we have an $f\in I$ and $g\in J$, at least one of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is guaranteed to be equal to $0$. Another way to write that is $$\forall f,g: f\in I \text{ AND } g\in J \implies fg(x)=0$$

Comment: Arthur Could you explain me why $x \notin V(I) \cup V(J)$ means that  there is an $f \in I$ and a $g \in J$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ ? Can it be that there are $f,g$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $g(x)=0$ ? :/

Answer (score 3):

Let $x \in V(I \cap J) \Rightarrow f(x) = 0, \forall f \in I \cap J.$ Suppose there exists $h \in I$ such that $h(x) \neq 0.$ The for any $g \in J, g(x) = 0,$ because $hg \in I \cap J.$

Comment: Does $f(x)=0, \forall f \in I \cap J$ mean that there exists $h \in I$ and $g \in J$ such that $f=hg$ ? If so, why is it like that?

Comment: Not necessarily. First of all, it can be that $IJ \subsetneq I \cap J,$ and even if $IJ = I \cap J,$ not all the elements of $I \cap J$ is of the form $hg$ for some $h \in I, g \in J.$ But it is always true that $V(IJ) = V(I \cap J).$